# Pandas Rolling Sum

Tags: sql, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data:

```
            country  objectid  objectuse
record_date
2022-07-20    chile         0          4
2022-07-01    chile         1          4
2022-07-02    chile         1          4
2022-07-03    chile         1          4
2022-07-04    chile         1          4
...             ...       ...        ...
2022-07-26     peru      3088          4
2022-07-27     peru      3088          4
2022-07-28     peru      3088          4
2022-07-30     peru      3088          4
2022-07-31     peru      3088          4
```

The data describes the daily usage of an object within a country for a single month (July 2022), and not all object are used every day.

I am interested in finding the sum of the monthly maximums for the month, easy enough:

```py
df.groupby(['country', 'objectid']).max().groupby(level=0).sum()

         objectuse
country
chile         1224
peru         17008
```

However the thing that I am actually interested in is creating a rolling sum of the object maxima up to each day in the month within a country, for example:

```
            country       sum  
record_date
2022-07-01    chile         1
2022-07-01     peru         1
2022-07-02    chile         2
2022-07-02     peru         3
...             ...       ...
2022-07-31    chile       1224
2022-07-31     peru      17008
```

Is there a way to do this in pandas? I ultimately also want to do this via SQL but I was trying to find an approach that works first via pandas and without using the obvious approach which is looping and filtering the data based on the period that I am interested.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what _"...  a rolling sum of the object maxima ..."_ exactly means (maybe provide a small MRC/sample with expected outptut)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
res = (
    df
    .sort_index()
    .pivot_table(
        index=["record_date", "country"], columns="objectid", values="objectuse",
        aggfunc="max", fill_value=0
    )
    .groupby(level=1).cummax(axis=0)
    .sum(axis=1)
)
```

As an illustration I'm using the following sample dataframe:

```py
from random import seed, randint, choices

seed(12345678)
objectids = list(range(10))
data = [
    [date, country, objectid, randint(1, 25)]
    for date in pd.date_range("2022-07-01", "2022-07-31", freq="1D")
    for country in ("chile", "peru")
    for objectid in choices(objectids, k=randint(0, 10))
]
df = (
    pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["record_date", "country", "objectid", "objectuse"])
    .set_index("record_date")
    .sample(frac=0.7, random_state=12345678)
    .sort_index()
)
```

```
            country  objectid  objectuse
record_date                             
2022-07-01     peru         5         11
2022-07-01     peru         5          5
2022-07-01    chile         6          8
2022-07-01     peru         7          4
2022-07-02     peru         8          2
...             ...       ...        ...
2022-07-31     peru         4          1
2022-07-31    chile         6         22
2022-07-31    chile         0          9
2022-07-31    chile         2          2
2022-07-31    chile         9         11

[215 rows x 3 columns]
```

Your first part

```
df.groupby(['country', 'objectid']).max().groupby(level=0).sum()
```

yields

```
         objectuse
country           
chile          226
peru           233
```

And the code above results in

```
record_date  country
2022-07-01   chile        8
             peru        15
2022-07-02   chile       34
             peru        58
2022-07-03   chile       83
2022-07-04   chile      120
             peru        71
2022-07-05   chile      155
             peru        97
...          ...        ...
2022-07-27   chile      226
             peru       232
2022-07-28   chile      226
             peru       232
2022-07-29   chile      226
             peru       233
2022-07-30   peru       233
2022-07-31   chile      226
             peru       233
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I am getting `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`; forgot to mention that each object id is not unique across countries.

Comment: @ManuelMartinez Thanks for the feedback. See my edit, maybe that's more like it?

Comment: That indeed does the trick! Now I got to figure out how to do it in SQL...

Answer (score 0):

You can use cumulative sum for this after filtering the countries out. You can probably reduce the redundancy in my code here by defining a function.

```
#create sample DataFrame
df=pd.DataFrame(['A','C','A','B','C','C','B','C'], columns=['country'])
df['sum1']=[4,7,9,5,8,2,5,9]

#filtering and using cumsum to add all
#nan values are used to skip those rows when using cumsum function
df['countryA']=[df.sum1[i] if df.country[i]=='A' else np.nan for i in range(len(df))]
df['countryA']=df.countryA.cumsum()
df['countryB']=[df.sum1[i] if df.country[i]=='B' else np.nan for i in range(len(df))]
df['countryB']=df.countryB.cumsum()
df['countryC']=[df.sum1[i] if df.country[i]=='C' else np.nan for i in range(len(df))]
df['countryC']=df.countryC.cumsum()

#replacing nan values to 0 to add all columns into 1
df.replace(np.nan,0,inplace=True)
df['sum_country']=df.countryA+df.countryB+df.countryC
df.drop(['countryA','countryB','countryC'],axis=1,inplace=True)

df
```