# SQL Window Function over sliding time window

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have the following data:

```
            country  objectid  objectuse
record_date
2022-07-20    chile         0          4
2022-07-01    chile         1          4
2022-07-02    chile         1          4
2022-07-03    chile         1          4
2022-07-04    chile         1          4
...             ...       ...        ...
2022-07-26     peru      3088          4
2022-07-27     peru      3088          4
2022-07-28     peru      3088          4
2022-07-30     peru      3088          4
2022-07-31     peru      3088          4
```

The data describes the daily usage of an object within a country for a single month (July 2022), and not all object are used every day. One of the things I am interested in finding is the sum of the monthly maximums for the month:

```
WITH month_max AS (
    SELECT
        country,
        objectid,
        MAX(objectuse) AS maxuse
    FROM mytable
    GROUP BY
        country,
        objectid
)
SELECT
    country,
    SUM(maxuse)
FROM month_max
GROUP BY country;
```

Which results in this:

```
country   sum
-------------
chile    1224
peru    17008
```

But what I actually want is to get the rolling sum of the maxima from the beginning of the month up to each date. So that I get something that looks like:

```
            country       sum  
record_date
2022-07-01    chile         1
2022-07-01     peru         1
2022-07-02    chile         2
2022-07-02     peru         3
...             ...       ...
2022-07-31    chile       1224
2022-07-31     peru      17008
```

I tried using a window function like this to no avail:

```
SELECT
    *,
    SUM(objectuse) OVER (
        PARTITION BY country
        ORDER BY record_date ROWS 30 PRECEDING
    ) as cumesum
FROM mytable
order BY cumesum DESC;
```

Is there a way I can achieve the desired result in SQL?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: For what it's worth, I asked the [same question but on Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73466364/pandas-rolling-sum/73475464#73475464) and I received an answer; perhaps it helps to figure out how to do it in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What ended up working is probably not the most efficient approach to this problem. I essentially created backwards looking blocks from each day in the month back towards the beginning of the month. Within each of these buckets I get the maximum of `objectuse` for each `objectid` within that bucket. After taking the max, I sum across all the maxima for that backward looking period. I do this for every day in the data.

Here is the query that does it:

```
WITH daily_lookback AS (
    SELECT
        A.record_date,
        A.country,
        B.objectid,
        MAX(B.objectuse) AS maxuse
    FROM mytable AS A
    LEFT JOIN mytable AS B
        ON A.record_date >= B.record_date
        AND A.country = B.country
        AND DATE_PART('month', A.record_date) = DATE_PART('month', B.record_date)
        AND DATE_PART('year', A.record_date) = DATE_PART('year', B.record_date)
    GROUP BY
        A.record_date,
        A.country,
        B.objectid
)
SELECT
    record_date,
    country,
    SUM(maxuse) AS usetotal
FROM daily_lookback
GROUP BY 
    record_date,
    country
ORDER BY
    record_date;
```

Which gives me exactly what I was looking for: the cumulative sum of the `objectid` maximums for the backward looking period, like this:

```
            country       sum  
record_date
2022-07-01    chile         1
2022-07-01     peru         1
2022-07-02    chile         2
2022-07-02     peru         3
...             ...       ...
2022-07-31    chile       1224
2022-07-31     peru      17008
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your inner query to use the windowed maximum:

```
WITH month_max AS (
    SELECT record_date, country, objectid,
        MAX(objectuse) over (PARTITION BY country, objectid ORDER BY record_date) AS mx
    FROM mytable
)
SELECT record_date, country, SUM(mx) as "sum"
FROM month_max
GROUP BY record_date, country;
```

This does assume one row per object per date.

Here's a re-written version of your query. With indexing it seems possible that it might run faster:

```
select record_date, country, min(usetotal) as usetotal
from mytable d inner join lateral (
    select distinct sum(max(objectuse)) over () as usetotal from mytable a
    where a.record_date between date_trunc('month', d.record_date) and d.record_date
      and a.country = d.country
    group by objectid
) T on 1 = 1
group by record_date, country
order by record_date, country;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=63760e30aecf4c885ec4967045b6cd03

Comment: Thanks for this response. However I think that this doesn't work because since the objectid can occur many times in the month, I would be summing it twice (or however many times it occurs in the month) but I just want to keep the maximum of it within the period of time I am summing over.

Comment: @ManuelMartinez Looking at your solution I believe all you need was to group by `record_date`.

Comment: Thanks again - but grouping by `record_date` only sums the `objectid`s that happen on that day, but I want to sum all the ones from that day all the way back to the beginning of the month; but just their max in the period.

Comment: @ManuelMartinez It sums from the previously looked up rolling maxima. It's the same thing that you do but without the self join.

Comment: Then I must be doing something wrong because when I ran your query and the one I posted I get different results. I believe the difference comes from the fact that even though you are summing the rolling max for each object id within a day, you are only summing the object ids that happened ON THAT DAY instead of all the ones that occurrent BEFORE that day.

Comment: @ManuelMartinez The problem is actually that I had the impression all date-object pairs were represented in the data. (See my note.) Your query fills that hole by generating the missing results. So in fact my query is undercounting.

Comment: That's exactly right - I guess that another way to this and avoiding the self-join is to backfill the missing objectids in the past without having to do the group by, but I wasn't really sure how to do this. I am hoping someone figures out a more efficient way to do this because the self join and double group by is pretty expensive. Thanks!

Comment: @ManuelMartinez I took a stab at improvement. Fingers crossed,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247597/discussion-between-manuel-martinez-and-shawnt00).